# Use transaction with ASP.NET identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am using ASP.NET identites userManager.CreateAsync so it automatically populates NormalizedEmail from email field and stuff like that. However this time I want to insert user together with some metadata (in some other tables) which means I need transaction.

I successfully made it work without throwing exception but it seems transaction **is not rollbacked** (UserManager uses some different dbContext?)

Here is code:

```
try
            {
                await ResilientTransaction.New(_databaseContext).ExecuteAsync(async () =>
            {


                var currentUser = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(_identityContext.UserId.ToString());

                user.ParentUserId = _identityContext.UserId;
                var existingUserWithEmail = await FindByEmailAsync(user.Email);
                if (existingUserWithEmail != null)
                {
                    throw new ValidationException($"User with email {user.Email} already exists");
                }
                var currentUserRoles = await _roleRepository.GetWithPermissionsByUserId(_identityContext.UserId);

                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
                var rolesResult = await _userManager.AddToRolesAsync(user, currentUserRoles.Select(x => x.Name));
                if (!result.Succeeded)
                {
                    throw new ValidationException(result.Errors.FirstOrDefault()!.Description);
                }

                if (currentUser.OverrideVehicleAccessSettingsByEmailDomainName)
                {
                    user.OverrideVehicleAccessSettingsByEmailDomainName = true;
                    var vehicleAccessSettings = await _vehicleAccessSettingRepository.GetAll(x => x.UserId == _identityContext.UserId);
                    foreach (var vehicleAccessSetting in vehicleAccessSettings)
                    {
                        vehicleAccessSetting.UserId = user.Id;
                        //  vehicleAccessSetting.Id = 0;
                        _ = await _vehicleAccessSettingRepository.Insert(vehicleAccessSetting);
                    }
                }
                user.Roles = currentUserRoles;

            });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
```

And this ResillianteTransaction is just this:

```
public class ResilientTransaction
    {
        private readonly DbContext _context;

        private ResilientTransaction(DbContext context) =>
            _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        public static ResilientTransaction New(DbContext context) =>
            new ResilientTransaction(context);

        public async Task ExecuteAsync(Func<Task> action)
        {
            // Use of an EF Core resiliency strategy when using multiple DbContexts
            // within an explicit BeginTransaction():
            // https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-resiliency
            var strategy = _context.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();
            await strategy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
            {

                await using var transaction = await _context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
                try
                {
                    await action();
                    await transaction.CommitAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    await transaction.RollbackAsync();
                    throw;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: The document you linked to in the comments recommends using a `TransactionScope` when multiple contexts are involved.

Comment: TransactionScope is not working since I get error Execution strategy 'SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy' does not support user-initiated transactions

Comment: See the code under ["This approach can also be used with ambient transactions"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-resiliency#execution-strategies-and-transactions) in the linked document.

Comment: creation of user is not rollbacked after creation (proabbly because my UserManager uses diferent db context)  when error happens later in code !

Comment: I'm afraid EF core doesn't support this ,  you can read [this](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/24586) .

Comment: What I did in the end is _myDatabaseContext.Users.Add(userWithManuallyCreatedNormalizedUserNameAndEmail) instaead of using userManager to CreateAsync